# Laravel route parameter not working

Tags: php, laravel

Any help why this is not working ,I am using Laravel 5.5.23 version ,this is are my routes :

```
<?php



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('threads','ThreadController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('threads','ThreadController@index');
Route::get('threads/{channel}','ThreadController@index');
Route::get('threads/create','ThreadController@create');
Route::get('threads/{channel}/{thread}','ThreadController@show');
Route::post('threads','ThreadController@store');
Route::post('/threads/{channel}/{thread}/replies','ReplyController@store');
Route::get('/logout' , 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

This is the ThreadController ,just the relevant methods actually :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
    }

    public function index($channel = null)
    {
        if($channel){
            //do something
        }
        else{
            $threads=Thread::latest()->get();
        }
        return view('threads.index',compact('threads'));
    }
```

The problem is when I try to access /threads/someChannel it returns not found ,so this is the problematic route : `Route::get('threads/{channel}','ThreadController@index');`  ,all other routes are working ,any idea why this one is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route::resource('threads','ThreadController')` call is defining 7 routes with the prefix `threads`. Some of the routes you are defining yourself are being masked by this. Check `php artisan route:list` to see what routes the `Route::resource` call registers for you first. First come first serve when it comes to matching routes.

`/threads/someChannel` is going to match the route defined by the `resource` call:

```
GET        /threads/{thread}        ThreadController@show
```

Since you don't have the definition for `show` which is **relevant** to have, I would assume you have Implicit Model Binding happening. It is trying to bind that model to that parameter and it can't find it in the database by that ID and is causing a 404 because of it.

Comment: Thank you ,I forgot to delete Route::resource() ,its working now ,thanks